# ng-if never returns to true with query

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I didn't explain what i wanted to achieve very well so i will try again.
I have a search bar and a last viewed list in my main view, what i am trying to do is hide the last viewed list when the user starts typing in the search bar and unhide it when the search bar is empty.
 With the current code i am using it displays the last viewed list at first and hides when the user starts typing however it is never unhidden when the search box is cleared.

I have included the whole view now and the search i am using is still the same as the two lines below.

I have since determined that when the user clears the search box the query no longer equals {}, which shows the last viewed list, but it equals {$: ""} which hides it.

I am trying to use ng-if to hide and unhide parts of the DOM, however when ng-if is triggered it never returns to true and doesn't recreate the DOM.

```
<ion-view view-title="GE Office Finder">
<!-- Favourites button -->
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button icon ion-android-star" ui-sref="Favourites">
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <!-- Search function starts here -->
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-subheader">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" id="search-criteria" placeholder="City, Country or Office Name" ng-model="query[queryBy]">
        </label>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <!-- Search function ends here -->


    <ion-content has-subheader>
        <!-- Main content starts here -->
        <!-- ng-show hides the list of offices and displays them when the user starts searching  -->
        <ion-list ng-if="query[queryBy]">
        <!-- Creates each item through collection-repeat and is filtered by the query linked to the search field -->
        <!-- ng-click opens the modal that will have the enlarged office address and the map of the office -->
            <ion-item class="item-text-wrap item-icon-right" id="output" collection-repeat="office in offices|filter:query" ng-controller="ModalCtrl" ng-click="openModal(office.Lat, office.Long); lastview(office.id);">
                <!-- Outputs all the data from offices.json -->
                <h3 id="LocName">{{office.LocationName}}</h3>
                <!-- the span prevents null data from being output causing empty space to be displayed -->
                <p id="details"><span ng-if="office.LocAddressLine1">{{office.LocAddressLine1}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocAddressLine2">, {{office.LocAddressLine2}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocCity">, {{office.LocCity}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocCountryDescription">, {{office.LocCountryDescription}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocZipPostalCode">, {{office.LocZipPostalCode}}</span></p>

                <!-- Creates the favourite icon on each list item, when the star is clicked the togglefav function is run -->
                <i ng-class="{'icon ion-android-star': favicon(office.id), 'icon ion-android-star-outline': !favicon(office.id)}" ng-click="togglefav(office.id); $event.stopPropagation();"></i>
            </ion-item>
    </ion-list>


    <ion-list id="cont">
        <!-- Last view offices list -->
        <div ng-if="!query[queryBy]">
                <h3 class="title" id="text">Last Viewed</h3>
            <!-- the filter with this collection repeat runs the function ifinfav2 which only displays items in the localstorage -->
                <ion-item id="fav" class="item-text-wrap item-icon-right" ng-repeat="office in offices|filter:ifinfav2" ng-controller="ModalCtrl" ng-click="openModal(office.Lat, office.Long);">
                <h3>{{office.LocationName}}</h3>
                <p id="details"><span ng-if="office.LocAddressLine1">{{office.LocAddressLine1}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocAddressLine2">, {{office.LocAddressLine2}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocCity">, {{office.LocCity}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocCountryDescription">, {{office.LocCountryDescription}}</span><span ng-if="office.LocZipPostalCode">, {{office.LocZipPostalCode}}</span></p>
                <i ng-class="{'icon ion-android-star': favicon(office.id), 'icon ion-android-star-outline': !favicon(office.id)}" ng-click="togglefav(office.id); $event.stopPropagation();"></i>
                </ion-item>
        </div>
        </ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This is the query that i am using. Its not in a function, just in the controller.

```
  $scope.query = {}
  $scope.queryBy = '$'
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? query is falsy by default when you do assign empty object to it. and `query[queryBy]` can only be used if the `query.$` is there... or whatever is in queryBy

Comment: Are you sure your controller is instantiated at this point in time? With the values you posted `!query[queryBy]` is truthy, and your code should render that div. Slap a console.log before your $scope.query and make sure it runs.

Comment: @JordyvanEijk `query` is truthy by default. `Boolean({})`

Comment: @The `query` is evaluated to `true` but `query[queryBy]` to `false`.

Comment: @sp00m yeap you are right

Comment: what i am trying to do is hide part of the DOM when the user starts typing in the input field which does happen but once the user deletes the text it should recreate the DOM but doesn't

Comment: why not write a function that will check every time something changes.. But watch out not to make it too big and heavy because it is evaluated a lot... due to the $digest